# css（internal style sheet） loading probrom

Tags: jquery, html, css

css（internal style sheet） don’t loading ,need refresh page

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

h2.name{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
}
img{
    padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
    max-width:290px;

}
p{
    padding:0px 20px 5px 20px;
}

</style>

</head>
```

I don't want to use javascript refresh page again

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please look at it again and try to explain exactly what it is you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

Close your `meta name="viewport"` tag, it's open and could be stopping the styles from loading.

Comment: ...and don't do this `maximum-scale=1.0`....it's very poor user experience.

Comment: Bootstrap suggests this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. Which I use and works fine for myself.

Comment: I have no problem with `initial-scale`...but I wear glasses and disabling scaling (as `maximum-scale-1.0` does) means I can't read it.